# TeXmaker fails to recognize new TeX Live installation

Tags: pdftex, packages, texlive, chemmacros

I have an older TeX Live 2019 version installed on macOS (10.12.6).

Recently I have installed TeX Live 2023 via MacPorts. I am using Sphinx v7.2.6 for generating a pdf file using command `make latexpdf`. After the completion of the process, I find that in log file `some_project.log`, somehow the older version (2019) of TeX Live is *still* being accessed:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=latex 2020.8.11)  29 JAN 2024 14:03 entering extended mode  restricted \write18 enabled.
```

Whereas in the terminal the logs generated during the run reads like:

```
Running Sphinx v7.2.6
loading pickled environment... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
writing output... 
building [latex]: all documents

...
...

Rc files read:
  latexmkrc
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 6 Nov. 2023. Version 4.81.

No existing .aux file, so I'll make a simple one, and require run of *latex. 
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'.

...
...

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/MacPorts 2023.66589_3)
(preloaded format=pdflatex) restricted \write18 enabled. entering extended mode
(./some_project.tex LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1 L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>

(./sphinxmanual.cls 
Document Class: sphinxmanual 2019/12/01 v2.3.0 Document class (Sphinx manual)
```

Here it ***points to the 2019 version again***. Is this to be expected?

It is apparent that somewhere pdftex is unable to get the right executable.

To check it further, I tried to create a dummy page using *TexMaker* with rudimentary codes comprising a preamble, begin and end document and a line of math code (which compiled correctly). In the *log* area of the TexMaker editor, I find that the *first line of the log* refers to the *2019 version*.

Moreover, when I try to load something else (say `mhchem`) it started throwing errors about an *associated source file* (`chemgreek.sty`) and the document won't compile, such as:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> Chem\str_uppercase:f
{\tl_head:n {alpha}}\str_lowercase:f {\tl_ta...
l.584 \chemgreek_drop_symbols:
The control sequence at the end of the top line
```

Could this behavior have something to do with wrong executables being used during the build process?

The executable (ver. 2023) is located in the path `/opt/local/bin/`.

Kindly advise me as to what am I doing wrong. Or, how do I **force** TeX Live (or TexMaker) to use the new installation instead of the old one (2019).

Thank you.

Comment: I tried MacPorts several years ago and soon abandoned it. Install TeX Live with MacTeX https://tug.org/mactex

Comment: Most LaTeX editors on Mac expects you to install MacTeX and it places the binaries in a very specific location (where the installation behind it can easily be changed). `/opt/local/bin` is not that PATH. So either reconfigure your texmaker or so as egreg mentioned, install MacTeX (remember to update MacTeX after installation, the ease of installation, it is the easiest by far to install, comes with the price of not containting the recent updates)

Comment: Your are right about installing MacTex. But my problem is _2023_ rel is for OS 10.14+. Looking for a solution installed TexShop but did not solve my issue. (Also I found TexShop a bit of a mess - may be I have gotten used to TexMaker!). What I have done now is: **Changed** the config settings of TexMaker for the two fields: _LaTeX_ and _PdfLaTeX_ from their default values `"latex" -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` and `"pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` to the paths `/opt/local/bin/` as stated in my question above. Now the docs compile without error (incl. chemical formulas).

Comment: ... _Just to add_ - now the **log file shows**: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/MacPorts 2023.66589_4) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.1.30)`. And thanks - @daleif - for pointing to the possible way out - which I had missed completely, only now I noticed :( as I am posting this.